# Crystal Reports Missing Parameter Values

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am running the version of crystal that comes with Visual Studio 2010. I have a report that has three sub reports. There are parameters that are passed from the main report to the sub-reports. I am able to run the report in the development environment by clicking on Main Report Preview.

The problem is when I try to execute it at run time. I get the error “Missing parameter values”. I need some hints as to how to debug this problem. The error doesn’t tell you which parameter is the problem or which sub-report is   involved.

Any hint will be appreciated.

I am editing this to respond to some of the questions. I am using subreports links which is where I think the problem might be. In the pass by fiddling with the settings I was able to get it to work. It seems like it was just trial and error.

I am posting a portion of the code here based on the request in the comments

```
 Public Function GetReportOutput(iDatabaseIndicator As eDatabaseIndicatorEnum, ReportName As String, ReportOutputtype As eReportOutputtype, ReportParameters As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of clsReportParam)) As clsReturn Implements IsvcEDReports.GetReportOutput
    Dim l_crRep As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    Dim l_clsReturn As clsReturn = New clsReturn
    Dim l_ExportFormatType As ExportFormatType


    Dim l_strReport As String = ""
    Dim l_strReportName As String = ""
    Dim l_strOutputFile As String = ""
    Dim l_strFullPathName As String = ""

    Dim l_strReportOutputPath As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(IIf(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Environment") = 1, "ReportOutputPath_Dev", "ReportOutputPath_Prod"))
    Dim l_strReportPath As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(IIf(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Environment") = 1, "ReportPath_Dev", "ReportPath_Prod"))

    Dim l_udtReport As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument = Nothing
    Dim l_intCount As Integer = 0
    Dim l_fsReturn As FileStream = Nothing
    Dim l_binFilestream As BinaryReader = Nothing
    Dim l_bytFile As Byte() = Nothing

    Dim l_expOptions As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportOptions
    Dim l_expExcFmtOptions As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExcelFormatOptions

    Dim l_tblParameters As New DataTable("Parameters")
    Dim l_aryParams(1)

    Dim udtSubReport As ReportDocument
    Dim udtSubReportOpened As ReportDocument


    Try
        iDatabaseIndicator = iDatabaseIndicator
        InitDataController(iDatabaseIndicator)
        m_strReport = (l_strReportPath & "\" & ReportName)


        l_strReportName = ReportName
        l_strReport = m_strReport
        l_strOutputFile = Regex.Replace(ReportName, " ", "_") & "_" & Format(Now(), "MMddyyyy_hhmmss")

        m_strOutputFilename = l_strOutputFile


        With l_crRep
            .Load(l_strReport, CrystalDecisions.Shared.OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByDefault)
            If .IsLoaded Then
                For Each udtSubReport In .Subreports
                    udtSubReportOpened = .OpenSubreport(udtSubReport.Name)
                    SetDatabase(udtSubReportOpened, False)
                    SetParameters(udtSubReportOpened, ReportParameters, False)
                Next
                SetDatabase(l_crRep)
                SetParameters(l_crRep, ReportParameters)


                Select Case ReportOutputtype
                    'Case eReportOutputtype.rptOutputType_RPT
                    '    l_strOutputFile = l_strOutputFile & ".rpt"
                    '    l_ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.CrystalReport
                    Case eReportOutputtype.rptOutputType_XLS
                        l_strOutputFile = l_strOutputFile & ".xls"
                        'ReportOutputFile = ReportOutputFile & ".xls"
                        With l_expExcFmtOptions
                            .ExcelConstantColumnWidth = 125
                            .ExcelUseConstantColumnWidth = True

                        End With
                        With l_expOptions
                            .ExportFormatOptions = l_expExcFmtOptions
                        End With
                        l_ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.Excel
                    Case eReportOutputtype.rptOutputType_PDF
                        l_strOutputFile = l_strOutputFile & ".pdf"
                        ' ReportOutputFile = ReportOutputFile & ".pdf"
                        l_ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat


                    Case eReportOutputtype.rptOutputType_DOC
                        l_strOutputFile = l_strOutputFile & ".doc"
                        ' ReportOutputFile = ReportOutputFile & ".doc"
                        l_ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.WordForWindows
                    Case eReportOutputtype.rptOutputType_CSV
                        l_strOutputFile = l_strOutputFile & ".csv"
                        '  ReportOutputFile = ReportOutputFile & ".csv"
                        l_ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.CharacterSeparatedValues
                    Case eReportOutputtype.rptOutputType_TXT
                        l_strOutputFile = l_strOutputFile & ".txt"
                        '  ReportOutputFile = ReportOutputFile & ".txt"
                        l_ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.Text
                    Case eReportOutputtype.rptOutputType_XML
                        l_strOutputFile = l_strOutputFile & ".xml"
                        '  ReportOutputFile = ReportOutputFile & ".xml"
                        l_ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.Xml

                End Select

                .ExportToDisk(l_ExportFormatType, l_strReportOutputPath & "\" & l_strOutputFile)
```

It crashes on the last line .ExportToDisk ...

Comment: How are you passing parameters from vb.net?

Comment: Are you using "sub report links"?

Comment: Add your code to the question.

Comment: I am using subreport links

Comment: Post the part of the code where you fill the parameters. I understand this problem occurs when the main report is missing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, It was the hint from heringer that gave me the clue. I am passing 6 parameters to the main report but two of them are only used by the a sub-report not the main reports itself. I was defining these without the leading "@". I figured this out by display the parameters as I passed them in my code.

I was also able to look at an old report that was working and saw that I needed the at signs.

Bob